# Most drives read only

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, drive, read-only

Im running Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS (with kde plasma) and for some reason, all drives (except my boot drive) have switched to read only. The drives are fine. Even the second partition on my boot drive (250GB boot/600GB Data) is now read only, with the os booting proving that the drive is fine. It is read only in Dophin and also cannot be written to via terminal and sudo. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you dual boot with Windows?  If so, you must disable fast startup in Windows. Have you done this?

Comment: @Nmath I did, but my win10 corrupted so I can't really do anything about the settings on there

Comment: Well that is the solution if Windows has locked the drives.  Fix your Windows problem. You can ask about it on SuperUser.

Comment: @Nmath would completely reinstalling windows fix the issue or make it worse. I couldn't find another way to fix the issue

Comment: A proper reinstallation followed by disabling Fast Startup should do it but, again, questions about Windows are off-topic here, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Problem is I want to backup some personal data to those locked drives, as I dont have a external/usb drive. Can I still somehow write to them?

Comment: This is not really the place to ask about Windows issues.  I am not comfortable advising on the topic.  I just know that fast startup is a hybrid suspend and that it makes certain hardware and storage devices unavailable when dual booting when the Windows system is suspended with fast startup

Comment: "I want to backup some personal data to those locked drives," You should think more about how to get the data in the bad drives to good drives, not put more data in the bad drives! First, backup the data in the read only partitions to external drives. I am voting to close this question as it is about corrupted Windows OS and partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

The issue was caused by fastboot from my dualbooted Windows installation. To fix it disable `fastboot` in the windows settings and when you reboot to linux it sould work